# jQuery .toggle woes

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, nav, jquery

My 1st question on here so I'll try to be as concise as possible.

I have a series of `nav` elements, some of which have `nav` sub-elements. My basic structure is:

```
    <nav role="navigation" class="primary-nav main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
            <li class="about-item"><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li class="study-item"><a href="#">study</a></li>
            <li class="apply-item"><a href="#">apply</a></li>
            <li><a href="people.php">people</a></li>
            <li><a href="shows.php">shows</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- secondary navs -->
    <!-- about -->
    <nav role="navigation" class="sec-nav sec-nav-about">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="history.php">history</a></li>
            <li><a href="facility.php">facility</a></li>
            <li><a href="alumni.php">alumni</a></li>
            <li><a href="friends.php">friends</a></li>
            <li><a href="patrons.php">patrons</a></li>
            <li><a href="singers.php">singers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- study -->
    <nav role="navigation" class="sec-nav sec-nav-study">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="foundation.php">foundation</a></li>
            <li class="study-undergrad-item"><a href="#">undergrad</a></li>
            <li class="study-postgrad-item"><a href="#">postgrad</a></li>
            <li><a href="parttime.php">part time</a></li>
            <li><a href="exams.php">exams</a></li>
            <li><a href="saturdayschool.php">saturday school</a></li>
            <li><a href="sundayschool.php">sunday school</a></li>
            <li><a href="summerschool.php">summer school</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<!-- apply -->
<nav role="navigation" class="sec-nav sec-nav-apply">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="loans.php">loans</a></li>
        <li><a href="auditions.php">auditions</a></li>
        <li><a href="fees.php">fees</a></li>
        <li><a href="exams.php">exams</a></li>
        <li><a href="saturdayschool.php">saturday school</a></li>
        <li><a href="sundayschool.php">sunday school</a></li>
        <li><a href="summerschool.php">summer school</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

(I know these lists could - and should - be nested but this is code I've inherited rather than written myself and I don't want to screw with anything else that might be in the styles).

So - what I want is when the 3rd, 4th and 5th main-nav items are clicked, their corresponding submenu animates using margin-left.

I'm currently using jQuery `.toggle()` to try and achieve this effect. Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.main-nav .about-item a').toggle (
    function(){
      $('.sec-nav-about').animate({marginLeft: "480"}, 500);
    },
    function(){
      $('.sec-nav-about').animate({marginLeft: "-250"}, 500);
    });

  $('.main-nav .study-item a').toggle (
    function(){
      $('.sec-nav-study').animate({marginLeft: "480"}, 500);
    },
    function(){
      $('.sec-nav-study').animate({marginLeft: "-250"}, 500);
    });
  $('.main-nav .apply-item a').toggle (
    function(){
      $('.sec-nav-apply').animate({marginLeft: "480"}, 500);
    },
    function(){
      $('.sec-nav-apply').animate({marginLeft: "-250"}, 500);
    });
  });
```

Up to this point, its fine. However, I cannot get beyond this point. I have no idea how to re-work the code to achieve the following:

1) When each main menu item is clicked, if it has a sub-menu and if its not already showing, then the sub-menu animates out (this is working fine).

2) If a sub-menu is already showing, then when its main menu item is clicked then the sub menu animates back in until its not showing (this is also working).

3) If a sub menu is showing and *another* sub menu item is clicked, the first sub-menu animates back in until its not showing *and* the new sub-menu animates out. This *not* working.

I have attempted to add/remove an `.active` class to each sub-menu like so (just one here for illustrative purposes but all three sub-menus have this applied to them):

```
$('.main-nav .about-item a').toggle (
  function(){
    $('.active').animate({marginLeft: "-250"}, 500).removeClass('active');
    $('.sec-nav-about').animate({marginLeft: "480"}, 500).addClass('active');
  },
  function(){
    $('.sec-nav-about').animate({marginLeft: "-250"}, 500).removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Then what happens is that, it seems to work and then after awhile, it stops removing/adding the `.active` class. I double checked in Chrome's Element Inspector and can see it (not) happening. I need to click the links *twice* to get the `toggle()` to work and drive the animation.

Any ideas/suggestions/solutions would be very gratefully appreciated.

(edited for spelling errors).

Thanks,

Comment: You have syntax error missing `.` and `'`. See incorrect highlighting?

Comment: Just wondering, when you copied in your code to show how you're adding/removing classes, did you miss the `.` in `$('.sec-nav-about').animate({marginLeft: "480"}, 500)addClass('active);`?

Comment: Thanks both - typo's on my part copying and pasting. The syntax is exactly as you both say it should be in the live code.

Comment: Can you create  a fiddle for this along with the styles.??

Comment: Yep - sorry, should've done that first. It's here: http://jsfiddle.net/ET475/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will Moore's answer explains why your current method doesn't work. The following should fix your problem. Using the regex on the className property means that we can apply this to all items in your list without having to set each one up individually.

Also, note that we query the 'sub menus to hide' before adding the `.active` class to the currently selected sub-menu; this avoids hiding it as soon as we show it.

```
$('.main-nav li').click(function() {
    var itemType = this.className.match(/(^| )([^ ]+)-item( |$)/);
    if(itemType != null) {
        itemType = itemType[2];
    }

    $secNavItem = $('.sec-nav-' + itemType);
    $subMenusToHide = $('.active');
    if(!$secNavItem.hasClass('active')) {
        $secNavItem
            .addClass('active')
            .animate({marginLeft: "480"}, 500);
    }

    $subMenusToHide
        .animate({marginLeft: "-250"}, 500)
        .removeClass('active');
});
```

You can see it working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ET475/23/

Comment: Thank you *very* much - thats excellent :) can I ask you - do you know any resources that *you* use/trust that I can learn more about regex?

Answer (score 0):

When you click 'Study' it SHOWS the study submenu.
Then you click the 'About' and it HIDES the study menu (shows the about menu).
Now you click 'Study' again. This is only the second click on the study button, so it's going to do the opposite of the last time you clicked it: ie it's going to HIDE the study submenu when you want it to show the study menu.

This works for me:

```
$('.main-nav .about-item a').click (function(){
    var $submenu = $('.sec-nav-about');
    // if the submenu you want isn't showing...
    if (!$submenu.hasClass('active')) {
        // if any other submenu is showing, hide it...
        if ($('.active').length > 0){
            $('.active').animate({marginLeft: "-250"}, 500, function(){
             // ...show submenu AFTER previous submenu is hidden
             $submenu.animate({marginLeft: "480"}, 500).addClass('active');
            }).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            // no submenus showing: simply display
            $submenu.animate({marginLeft: "480"}, 500).addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, but for me all that happens is that if I click on the 'about' link, the about sub menu appears. Clicking on it again does nothing and clicking on either of the other two links do anything either. http://jsfiddle.net/zymQx/

Comment: That's the expected behaviour (if you haven't used the above code on the other menu items)! Clicking on the menu item that is already displayed shouldn't collapse it again, right? If you want it to collapse it, you could add an else statement right at the end to do $('.active').animate({marginLeft: "-250"}, 500)